# Parallelize collection in spark scala shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I trying to parallelize the tuple and getting error below. Please let me know that is the error in below syntax
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method parallelize need a Seq. Each item in the seq will be one record.

```
def parallelize[T](seq: Seq[T], 
  numSlices: Int = defaultParallelism)
  (implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): RDD[T]
```

In your example, you need add a Seq to wrap the Tuple, and in this case the RDD only has ONE record

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("100", List("5", "-4", "2", "NA", "-1"))))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[String])] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> rdd.count
res4: Long = 1
```